# Custom arguments in WP_Query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I am working on a Wordpress theme i.e. Directory engine. It is having a filtering functionality in the header based on taxonomy term slug. I just want to know from where this tax_query is generated for WP_Query.Here is the code.

```
 $this->add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_places');
 function pre_get_places($query) {
        global $current_user;

        if ($query->is_main_query() && is_author()) {
            $query->set('post_type', $this->post_type);
            if ($current_user->user_login == $query->query['author_name']) {
                $query->set('post_status', array(
                    'pending',
                    'reject',
                    'archive',
                    'draft',
                    'publish'
                ));
            }
        }
        // set default post type query in place category, location listing
        if ($query->is_main_query() && (is_tax('place_category') || is_tax('location') || is_tax('age_from') || is_tax('place_type') || is_tax('daddy_lounge') || is_tax('place_caregivers'))) {
            $query->set('post_type', $this->post_type);
            $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
        }

        /**
         * is main query and cach request showposts
         */
        if (isset($_REQUEST['showposts']) && $query->is_main_query()) {
            $query->set('showposts', $_REQUEST['showposts']);
        }

        /**
         * if is post type archive set status to publish
         */
        if (is_post_type_archive($this->post_type) && !is_admin()) {
            if (!isset($query->query_vars['post_status'])) {
                $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
            }
        }

        /**
         * filter orderby
         */
        if (isset($_REQUEST['sortby']) 
            && ( $query->is_main_query() || (isset($query->query_vars['meta_key']) && $query->query_vars['meta_key'] == 'rating_score') )
        ) {
            if ($_REQUEST['sortby'] !== 'date') {
                // $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_REQUEST['sortby'];
                $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            } else {

                // order by date
                $query->set('orderby', 'date');
            }

            // order desc
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        }
        // order by rating score
        if(isset($_REQUEST['query']['orderby']) && $_REQUEST['query']['orderby'] == 'rating_score') {
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num date');
            if( !isset($_REQUEST['query']['meta_key'] ) ) {
                $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = $_REQUEST['query']['orderby'];
                $query->meta_query = array(
                     //check to see if et_featured has been filled out
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         //check to see if date has been filled out
                        'key' => $_REQUEST['query']['orderby'],
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'value' => array(
                            0,
                            5
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                         //if no et_featured has been added show these posts too
                        'key' => $_REQUEST['query']['orderby'],
                        'value' => '',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    )
                );
            }else{
                // order by rating score for feature block
                if($_REQUEST['query']['meta_key'] == 'et_featured') {
                    $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
                    $query->set('meta_query' , array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'rating_score',
                            // 'value' => array(0, 5),
                            // 'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'et_featured',
                            'value' => '1',
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                        )
                    )); 
                }
                if($_REQUEST['query']['meta_key'] == 'de_event_post') {
                    // order by rating score for event block
                    $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
                    $query->set('meta_query' , array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'rating_score',
                            'value' => array(0, 5),
                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'de_event_post',
                            'value' => '',
                            'compare' => '!=', 
                            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                        )
                    )); 
                }            
            }
        }

        $is_search = ! (empty($_REQUEST['query']) || empty($_REQUEST['query']['s']));
        if ((et_load_mobile() && !is_single() ) && !$is_search) {
            if (!is_author() && isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == $this->post_type) {
                if(!is_search()){
                    $query->set('meta_key', 'et_featured'); 
                }
                if(!isset($query->query_vars['near_lat']) || $query->query_vars['near_lat'] == '' ){
                    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num date');
                }
                if (isset($query->query_vars['meta_value'])) {
                    unset($query->query_vars['meta_value']);
                }                
                $query->meta_query = array(
                     //check to see if et_featured has been filled out
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                         //check to see if date has been filled out
                        'key' => 'et_featured',
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                        'value' => array(
                            0,
                            1
                        )
                    ) ,
                    array(
                         //if no et_featured has been added show these posts too
                        'key' => 'et_featured',
                        'value' => 1,
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        return $query;
    }

 $args = array(
    "post_type" => "place",
    "post_status" => "publish",
    "orderby" => "date",
    "place_category" => "",
    "location" => "",
    "showposts" => "4",
    "order" => "DESC",
    "meta_key" => "et_featured",
    "meta_value" => "1",
    "paginate" => "page",
    "age_from" => "2",
    "age_to" => "5",
    "place_caregivers" => "no",
    "place_type" => "indoor",
    "daddy_lounge" => "no",
    "paged" => "1",
    "thumbnail" => "big_post_thumbnail",
    "posts_per_page" => false
};
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

$query returns

```
"data":null,
"paginate":"<script type=\"application\/json\" class=\"ae_query\">{\"post_type\":\"place \",\"post_status\":\"publish\",\"orderby\":\"date\",\"place_category\":\"\",\"location\":\"\",\"showposts \":\"4\",\"order\":\"DESC\",\"meta_key\":\"et_featured\",\"meta_value\":\"1\",\"paginate\":\"page\", \"age_from\":\"2\",\"age_to\":\"5\",\"place_caregivers \":\"no\",\"place_type\":\"indoor\",\"daddy_lounge\":\"no\",\"paged\":\"1\",\"thumbnail\":\"big_post_thumbnail \",\"posts_per_page\":false}<\/script>",
"msg":"Successs",
"success":true,
"max_num_pages":null,
"status":"0 place",
"total":0,
"total_status":{

    "publish":"71",
    "pending":0,
    "archive":"5",
    "reject":"1",
    "draft":"1"

},
"data_query":{

    "query":{
        "query":{
            "post_type":"place",
            "post_status":"publish",
            "orderby":"date",
            "place_category":"",
            "location":"",
            "showposts":"4",
            "order":"DESC",
            "meta_key":"et_featured",
            "meta_value":"1",
            "paginate":"page",
            "age_from":"2",
            "age_to":"5",
            "place_caregivers":"no",
            "place_type":"indoor",
            "daddy_lounge":"no",
            "paged":"1",
            "thumbnail":"big_post_thumbnail",
            "posts_per_page":false
        },
        "query_vars":{
            "post_type":"place",
            "post_status":"publish",
            "orderby":"date",
            "place_category":"",
            "location":"",
            "showposts":4,
            "order":"DESC",
            "meta_key":"et_featured",
            "meta_value":"1",
            "paginate":"page",
            "age_from":"2",
            "age_to":"5",
            "place_caregivers":"no",
            "place_type":"indoor",
            "daddy_lounge":"no",
            "paged":1,
            "thumbnail":"big_post_thumbnail",
            "posts_per_page":4,
            "error":"",
            "m":"",
            "p":0,
            "post_parent":"",
            "subpost":"",
            "subpost_id":"",
            "attachment":"",
            "attachment_id":0,
            "name":"",
            "static":"",
            "pagename":"",
            "page_id":0,
            "second":"",
            "minute":"",
            "hour":"",
            "day":0,
            "monthnum":0,
            "year":0,
            "w":0,
            "category_name":"",
            "tag":"",
            "cat":"",
            "tag_id":"",
            "author":"",
            "author_name":"",
            "feed":"",
            "tb":"",
            "comments_popup":"",
            "preview":"",
            "s":"",
            "sentence":"",
            "fields":"",
            "menu_order":"",
            "category__in":[
            ],
            "category__not_in":[
            ],
            "category__and":[
            ],
            "post__in":[
            ],
            "post__not_in":[
            ],
            "tag__in":[
            ],
            "tag__not_in":[
            ],
            "tag__and":[
            ],
            "tag_slug__in":[
            ],
            "tag_slug__and":[
            ],
            "post_parent__in":[
            ],
            "post_parent__not_in":[
            ],
            "author__in":[
            ],
            "author__not_in":[
            ],
            "ignore_sticky_posts":false,
            "suppress_filters":false,
            "cache_results":true,
            "update_post_term_cache":true,
            "update_post_meta_cache":true,
            "nopaging":false,
            "comments_per_page":"50",
            "no_found_rows":false,
            "taxonomy":"daddy_lounge",
            "term":"no"
        },
        "tax_query":{
            "queries":[
                {
                    "taxonomy":"age_from",
                    "terms":"2",
                    "field":"slug",
                    "operator":"IN",
                    "include_children":true
                },
                {
                    "taxonomy":"age_to",
                    "terms":"5",
                    "field":"slug",
                    "operator":"IN",
                    "include_children":true
                },
                {
                    "taxonomy":"place_caregivers",
                    "terms":[
                        "no"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug",
                    "operator":"IN",
                    "include_children":true
                },
                {
                    "taxonomy":"place_type",
                    "terms":[
                        "indoor"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug",
                    "operator":"IN",
                    "include_children":true
                },
                {
                    "taxonomy":"daddy_lounge",
                    "terms":[
                        "no"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug",
                    "operator":"IN",
                    "include_children":true
                }
            ],
            "relation":"AND",
            "queried_terms":{
                "age_from":{
                    "terms":"2",
                    "field":"slug"
                },
                "age_to":{
                    "terms":"5",
                    "field":"slug"
                },
                "place_caregivers":{
                    "terms":[
                        "no"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug"
                },
                "place_type":{
                    "terms":[
                        "indoor"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug"
                },
                "daddy_lounge":{
                    "terms":[
                        "no"
                    ],
                    "field":"slug"
                }
            },
            "primary_table":"wp_posts",
            "primary_id_column":"ID"
        },
        "meta_query":{
            "queries":{
                "0":{
                    "key":"et_featured",
                    "value":"1"
                },
                "relation":"OR"
            },
            "relation":"AND",
            "meta_table":"wp_postmeta",
            "meta_id_column":"post_id",
            "primary_table":"wp_posts",
            "primary_id_column":"ID"
        },
        "date_query":false,
        "request":"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt2 .object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( \n 0 = 1 \n AND \n 0 = 1 \n AND \n wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (130) \n AND \n tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (125) \n AND \n tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (128)\n) AND ( \n ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'et_featured' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '1' )\n) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'place' AND ((wp_posts .post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 4",
        "posts":[
        ],
        "post_count":0,
        "current_post":-1,
        "in_the_loop":false,
        "comment_count":0,
        "current_comment":-1,
        "found_posts":0,
        "max_num_pages":0,
        "max_num_comment_pages":0,
        "is_single":false,
        "is_preview":false,
        "is_page":false,
        "is_archive":true,
        "is_date":false,
        "is_year":false,
        "is_month":false,
        "is_day":false,
        "is_time":false,
        "is_author":false,
        "is_category":false,
        "is_tag":false,
        "is_tax":true,
        "is_search":false,
        "is_feed":false,
        "is_comment_feed":false,
        "is_trackback":false,
        "is_home":false,
        "is_404":false,
        "is_comments_popup":false,
        "is_paged":false,
        "is_admin":true,
        "is_attachment":false,
        "is_singular":false,
        "is_robots":false,
        "is_posts_page":false,
        "is_post_type_archive":true,
        "thumbnails_cached":false
    }
```

actualy i want OR relation in "age_to" taxonomy and "age_from" taxonomy and want AND relation with other Taxonomies like  "place_caregivers","place_type" and "daddy_lounge" but not able to find any way to edit tax_query.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is generating the tax query for you - when you register a custom taxonomy, it also registers what's known as a query var. This is a "key"-type value that means you can simply do this:

```
new WP_Query([ 'age_from' => 2 ]);
```

... and WP will transform that to:

```
WP_Tax_Query([
    [
        'taxonomy' => 'age_from',
        'terms'    => 2,
        'field'    => 'slug',
    ]
]);
```

...but not before `pre_get_posts` fires (it happens on line `2802` of `wp-includes/query.php`). My suggestion would be to use a direct tax query in your arguments, rather than taxonomy query vars, so you have complete control over the relationship:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'place',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'tax_query'   => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',

        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'age_from',
                'terms'    => '2',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'age_to',
                'terms'    => '5',
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'place_caregivers',
                'terms'    => 'no',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'place_type',
                'terms'    => 'indoor',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'daddy_lounge',
                'terms'    => 'no',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Read about ["nested" relations in WordPress 4.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/)